# Position update rate of GPS

Tags: navigation, gnss

GPS satellites send data at the rate of 50 bits per second. One GPS subframe is 6 seconds long. How is it possible to update one's position faster than once in 30 seconds when we require the whole frame (5 subframes adding up to 30 seconds) to extract the NavBits for the pseudorange calculation?

Comment: You might try this question at gis.SE some of the people there are experts in signal analysis.  But do keep in mind you generally need 4 satellites to get a reading and you can have up to 8 or 10 above the horizon, depending on location and altitude.

Comment: oversimplifying, 50 bits per second means there are approximately 50 opportunities for calculating some position from the signal delay. it's the timing what counts, not the actual information from the data frame.

Comment: @szulat Yes, I understand that I don’t need the entire data frame to calculate the time differences. But to solve the pseudo range equations I need the satellite’s coordinates, for which I may need the complete data frame, right?

Comment: satellite coordinates are predictable, once you get the complete initial information you can continue even though further updates are delayed by slow data transfer.

Comment: Also, a lot of "GPS" devices actually use information other than GPS as well. Mobile phones, for example, use the Internet (or the cellular network) to get most of the necessary data instead of getting it from the satellite. They use accelerometers, gyroscopes, compasses, and triangulation of cellular, WiFi, and Bluetooth signals as well. Plus, depending on where in the world you are, they also can use GLONASS, BeiDou, or Galileo in addition to GPS, so you may not only have more than the required 4 GPS satellites in view, but also a number of satellites from other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Position interpolation between readings based on last positions & speeds calculated?  Plenty of 10Hz update GPS units exist, so it doesn't seem be rocket science to get there.

Units can track 12 or more satellites.  If calculations are being made from several sets of readings, then multiple positions can be calcuted at any one time as well.